# addClass() in dependency of radio-field

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="radio" name="rb" class="rb_1">
        <input type="radio" name="rb" class="rb_2">
        <input type="radio" name="rb" class="rb_3">
    </div>
</div>
```

1. Now I want to add the class of the selected inputfield to the main-element. That means if I select the second radio-field, the result should be:
2. And the other way round: If the main-element has a .rb_*-class, the radio-field should be selected: If .main has the class 'rb_3' -> the third radio-field should be selected

**JS:**

```
// First question
$(".main").each(function () {
    var rb = $(this).children("input[type='radio']:checked").attr('class');
    if (rb) { $(this).addClass(rb);

});

/second question
$(".main").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass(".rb_*")) { 
        // get class value for var rb = ...
        $(this).children(rb).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
//check if main div has specific class & check the respective radio
$("input[class^='rb_']").each(function() {
    var rad = $(this),
        clname = rad.attr('class');
    //check if 'main' div has class as in checked radio
    if($("div.main").hasClass(clname)) {
        rad.prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

and

```
$("input[name='rb']").on("change", function() {
    var selected = $(this).prop('checked'),
        mainEle = $("div.main"),
        classNaam = $(this).attr('class');
    //remove all class from element
    mainEle[0].className = '';
    if(selected) {
        //add 'main' and class from checked radio
        mainEle.addClass('main ' + classNaam);
    }
    else { 
        //add only 'main' class       
        mainEle.addClass('main');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3o5rqowd/)